# Get function from string in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, string, function

I have some JavaScript function definitions stored in a string.

```
"function firstFun() {
  return 'some text';
}

function secondFun() {
  console.log(firstFun())
}"
```

Is it possible to access and call these functions like any other function?
Like:

```
var text = firstFun(); // return 'some text'
secondFun();           // print 'some text'
```

Comment: You could (but should not) use `eval` or parse the string by yourself. However, I would strongly recommend to reconsider your design.

Comment: It's possible, but should be avoided in almost all situations. Which problem should 'creating functions from strings' solve?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have stored JS code in string, you'll have to [`eval`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval) it (which is a dangerous operation - if you're running untrusted code as T.J. Crowder clarified):

```
const code = `
  function firstFun() {
    return 'some text';
  }

  function secondFun() {
    console.log(firstFun())
  }
`;

eval(code);
```

Comment: *"which is a dangerous operation"* Only if the content you're `eval`ing is from an untrusted source.

Comment: After I evaled how should I call the function? I tried the default way like I stated in my question, but I get an exception that "firstFun is not defined".

Comment: `firstFun` should be available in the context.

Comment: If anyone got the exception I had, maybe you're using strict mode and that's why it fails.

Answer (score 0):

Various ways ... even depending if you can change the format of the strings. But this should give you an idea. Keep in mind, that this can be dangerous, if you add such functionality to your scripts.

With `eval`:

```js
const code = `
  function firstFun() {
    return 'some text';
  }

  function secondFun() {
    console.log(firstFun())
  }
`;

eval(code);
secondFun();
```

Putting it in a `script` tag:

```js
const code = `
  function firstFun() {
    return 'some text';
  }

  function secondFun() {
    console.log(firstFun())
  }
`;

var head = document.querySelector('head');
var script = document.createElement('script');
script.type = 'text/javascript';
script.innerHTML = code;
head.appendChild(script);

secondFun();
```

Use `Function` constructor:

```js
const firstStr = `return 'some text';`;
const secondStr = `console.log(firstFun())`;

var firstFun = new Function(firstStr);
var secondFun = new Function(secondStr);

secondFun();
```